# How to concatenate multiple dataframes having different column names and length

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having multiple dataframes. All are having different column names and lengths. For example `df1` has columns like `['c1', 'c2', 'c3']`, `df2` has columns like `['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4']` and so on.

I want to concatenate all the `df`s one under another. I don't care about the column name preservation. Resultant `df` will have all the values of `df1` and `df2` and so on.

Right now I'm doing `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=0)` which is making the resultant `df` both `df1` and `df2` columns side by side. I want them one under another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If column names isn't important, we can also consider taking the numpy values of the dataframes by [`DataFrame.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html) and concat together using `pd.concat()`, like below:

```
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(dfi.values) for dfi in [df1, df2]], ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Lol, sooooo much simpler :faceplam:

Comment: @ALollz  Haha, just by luck I think of it.  Yours is already very good!  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Since your DataFrames can have a different number of columns, rename the labels to be their integer position that way they align underneath for the join. The result will have an `Int64Index` on the columns, up to the length of the widest DataFrame you provide in the `concat`.

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(['foo', 'bar'], (2, 3)),
                   columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(11, 20, (3, 4)),
                   columns=['d1', 'd2', 'd3', 'd4'])
```

#### Code

```
df = pd.concat([x.rename(columns=dict(zip(x.columns, range(x.shape[1])))) 
                for x in [df1, df2]],
               ignore_index=True) 

#     0    1    2     3
#0  foo  bar  foo   NaN
#1  foo  foo  foo   NaN
#2   17   12   14  17.0
#3   12   11   12  11.0
#4   11   14   15  11.0
```

Comment: I know I didn't add this in original question, but my column types are also different.

Comment: Also this doesn't work for multiple `df`s.

Comment: Can you check this - https://ideone.com/iUS77w. You will see 'a5' column didn't rename.

Comment: @AnirbanNag'tintinmj' oh my bad, I had a small typo, i was renaming based on the len, but it should have been the width of the DataFrame. Fixed that now